# Asp.NET MCV how to call a viewmodel function that performs a db connection on button click correctly?

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core

I have a few viewmodels, which contains a few functions like:

```
public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{M_IV_ID} {M_IV_INVOICEAMOUNT} {M_IV_MANDANT} {M_IV_TOTALAMOUNT} {M_IV_VEHICLE_PURCHASE} {M_IV_URGENT}";
        }
```

And update / insert functionalities. All of them work. I wrote them separately from my Asp.NET project and tested them since I wanted to do my back end first.

Now I tried to use those functions in my Asp.NET application:

First I get Data from the db in my Controller:

```
M_IV_INVOICE invoice = QueryBuilder.GetFirstOrDefault(new M_IV_INVOICE(), @"WHERE M_IV_ID IN (75693)");
```

And pass it to my view:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(invoice);
        }
```

Now I tried to use my toString() method just to see if  it works:

```
<form id="formUpdate" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:button id="Button" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server">Update</asp:button>
        </div>
    </form>
    @{
        string MyFunction()
        {

            return Model.ToString();
        }
    }

    @section Scripts
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
         document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
             var button = document.getElementById('Button');
             button.addEventListener('click', function () {
                var test = "@MyFunction()";
                console.log(test);
             });
        });
        </script>
    }
```

And if I do this, it works, and I get my model values printed in the browser console.

If I try to use my Update function instead of the toString() method:

```
 public bool Update()
        {
            using (IDbConnection conn = ConnectionManager.GetConnection())
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Query(QueryBuilder.BuildUpdateForEntity(this, string.Format(" WHERE {0} = {1}", GetKey().Item1, GetKey().Item2)));
                    return true;
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    // TODO: Exceptionhandling
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
```

I get a Ora Exception right when the page loads, no button click performed:

> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00936: missing expression

I struggle with understanding why, though.
The select I perform in my controller to get the data in the first place is working just fine, and as I said, if I print my model on button click, it works too.

What am I missing?

**Edit:**
It seems like the function is directly called while the eventhandler is added and since it has no data at the time, the ORA error is occurring.
But why? I don't understand this behavior.

**Another Edit:**
It has indeed something to do with the model isn't ready or something:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                    var button = document.getElementById('Button');
                    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
                        setTimeout(() => { console.log("@MyFunction()") }, 3000);
                        
                    });
            });

        </script>
```

I added the delay and no error on loading the page.
But that would be just a band aid, not a solution.
If someone has an idea how to prevent that behavior, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Hi @user3793935, based on your view page code, since you are using the `runat="server"` and `<asp:button>`, I assume your application is a traditional .Net Framework  MVC application, instead of an Asp.net Core application or Asp.net 5/6 application, right?

Comment: It is a core applikation. Didn't know this is the traditionell asp.net notation. After I stumbled across this problem, I started googling and tryed different possilbe solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@{}`symbol is used to write server-side C# or VB code with HTML code, so in the javascript, when you use the `@MyFunction()` function, the Myfunction will execute. You could set a break point in the MyFunction and the button click event to check it, no matter using the `ToString()` method or the `Update()` method, they will work when the DOMContent Loaded. So, when use the `Update()` method, you will meet the missing expression error.

Based on your description, you want to do some action (call the server-side function/method) when user clicks the button, right? If that is the case, I suggest in the controller you can add the Myfunction and Update action methods, then, in the button click event, you can use JQuery `get()`, `post()` or `Ajax` method to call the action method, refer the following code:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string name)
{
    PersonModel person = new PersonModel
    {
        Name = name,
        DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString()
    };
    return Json(person);
}
```

and View Page:

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" />
<input type="button" id="btnGet" value="Get Current Time" />


@section Scripts{ 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#btnGet").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Test/AjaxMethod",
                    data: { name: $("#txtName").val() }, 
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("Hello: " + response.name + " .\nCurrent Date and Time: " + response.dateTime);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        }); 
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you, I'll take a lock at those links later the day. 
Sad, I hoped that I can just call my Model function via button click without using a controller function. 
Is that the general approach for calling viewmodel functions?

Comment: @user3793935, the previous links is about Asp.net MVC, you can ignore them. And I have modified the reply to apply to Asp.net Core Application. Besides, as I said in my reply, the view's function is executed when the page load. When the page load,  you could consider adding an expression to get all data or default value, then in the button click event, try to call it with parameters.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your help. 
But now I have one problem left:
My model in the controller isn't recognising the changes I made in the view.
How do I solve this?
I tried it this way:     <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="Test" value="@Model.Test" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="0">
But when the update function is called, the model values are still the same as when I inititialized it and passed it to the view

Comment: @user3793935, in the update function, how do you get the text box value? using JQuery? The code works well on my side, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FBOx.png)(the initial value is SSS). Please check your JQuery selector make sure you are using the correct arrtibute to find the textbox.

Comment: If I do it the way you did, it works fine, true. 
but the behaviour I wanted would be that I bind a model property on an input field and if I click the button, the update method is called(wich works now, but not with the current input values). 
If I would do it with passing every single parameter, I would go insane (since I have a lot of models, some with 100+ propertys)
I thought if I bind the model via value to the input field, it's getting updated automatically, since I passed it from the controller.
Is there a way to archive the behaviour I described?